# How to export on premise database as bacpac directly to AZURE blob using command line

Tags: sql-server, export, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bacpac

We were able to create the bacpac using the below command,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin>

sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:. /sdn:demo  /tf:d:\bacpac\demo.bacpac

However we want to automate the below action,

[image]

Also can this be done via SSMS using something similar

BACKUP DATABASE  demo

TO URL = @FullName

WITH CREDENTIAL = democredential;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azcopy to upload those bacpac files to an Azure BLOB Storage account as shown below:

```
AzCopy /Source:"d:\bacpac" /Dest:"https://exampleaccount.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs" /DestKey:storageaccountkey /Pattern:*.bacpac
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
But we want to achieve this without AzCopy, sorry, i forgot to mention in question itself. Can we do this using sqlpackage or say PowerShell script?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Powershell Script,

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

To check the Status of the Export you can use the below one

```
$exportStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
[Console]::Write("Exporting")
while ($exportStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
{
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $exportStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
    [Console]::Write(".")   
}
[Console]::WriteLine("")
$exportStatus
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell)

If you want to Automate this by using [Azure Automation RunBook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook)

Comment: This is also correct answer, but i can't mark 2 answers or say alternative for single questions, so :)

Comment: I will then vote for Jayendran answer to make more justice. Thank you Manish and thank you Jayendran.